# scrollbar is appearing for element having height lesser than max-height

Tags: css, overflow

I'm having a div containing the list (unordered) and I have set the max-height of the list as 300px and overflow-y as auto but even if the list is not exceeding 300px, I can see the scroll bar.

```
<div class="category">
 <ul class="dynamicList">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>xyz</li>
  <li>mno</li>
  <li>pqr</li>
  <li>stu</li>
  <li>lmn</li>
  <li>wxy</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

note:list is dynamic

and css for class dynamicList

```
.dynamicList{
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto
}
```

Comment: delete the `<` after `<div class="category">`

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my end using your code.

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: Can you provide the exact same behavior that you're experiencing? I think something's overriding the `overflow-y: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.dynamicList{
  height:100px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Listbox</h1>
<div class="category">
 <ul class="dynamicList">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>xyz</li>
  <li>mno</li>
  <li>pqr</li>
  <li>stu</li>
  <li>lmn</li>
  <li>wxy</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you try this code? There is max height but no default height.

Comment: Thank you all, I tried it but the behaviour stayed same,later figured out the margin property of list element was causing the issue ,I just changed the margin to 0px which worked